# Run awk script on multiple files in a folder on Windows

Tags: windows, awk

I am new to awk. I have a list of .sql files in a folder and I need to run an AWK script on all of them.

I tried this on cmd (Windows):

```
for i in *.sql; do  awk -f script.awk $i > $i.out done
```

But it is not working. It says:

```
i was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: please update your Q and give an exact error message or other evidence that "it is not working". If there are spaces in your filenames (values of `$i`), then you must dbl-quote i.e. `"$i"`, but dbl-quoting variables is almost always a good idea.  Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: thank you. I have made the required edits. 
There are no spaces in filenames, nevertheless, I tried double-quoting but didn't help.

Comment: tag your question with whatever OS you're using as this has nothing to do with awk it's about how to execute command X on multiple files on your OS for any command name X.

Answer (score 0):

Missed a ';':

```
for i in *.sql; do  awk -f script.awk $i > $i.out ; done
```

Comment: It is saying 
'i was unexpected at this time.'

Answer (score 0):

Windows is using `%varname` and not `$varname`.

So something like this:

`for %i in (*.*) do awk -f script.awk "%i"`

It's good practice to remember the quotes, for file names with spaces.